# Lost partition after restarting

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, partitioning

I have Window 7 Professional Service pack 1 installed in my Laptop Lenovo Thinkpad t420.

After formatting the disk, and install Window 7 (detailed as above), I went to Computer --> Manager --> Storage --> Disk Management to split my 300gb C partition into 2 partitions:

- C (which is 162gb)
- E (which is 140gb)

It worked fine for about 2 days. Today, when I turn on my computer, I'm very surprise that the E partition is disappeared. I can surely confirm that I didn't do any stupid thing yesterday. And before I shut down my computer, everything was fine.

In general, here is what I did during the last two days (from the point that I formatted the disk, and installed Window)

- Format 300gb hard disk
- Install window 7
- Install eclipse, db2, .... ( I'm a developer)
- Install some other tools (Open office, Skype...)
- Install PGP (http://www.symantec.com/encryption) <--- I'm forced to use that due to my company policy
- Use Computer --> Manager --> Storage --> Disk Management to split my 300gb C partition into 2 partitions as described above.

It worked quite well for the last two days until today.

Can you please help me to recover my lost partition ?

Thank you!

For more info, here is my partition info:

[image]

You can also see the image [here](http://imageshack.us/a/img819/1362/rtsc.png)

Comment: Have you tried `gparted` from a LiveCD?

Comment: Not yet, will it fix the problem ?

Comment: I always debug Windows problems in Linux. Not sure if it'll help, but it usually at least clarifies the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Got it! Here is the step-by-step installation causing the problem:

1. Install PGP
2. Use PGP to encrypt the hard disk
3. Use Disk Management to create E partition (during encryption)
4. During the encryption, I was able to see E partition
5. After  the encryption, E partition is NOT found.

In fact, After the encryption, we cannot see E partition as it has already been encrypted by PGP.

To remedy it, we need:

1. Decrypt the whole hard disk using PGP
2. At that time, we will be able to see E partition again
3. Encrypt the whole hard disk, including C and E

**And here is the lesson learned:** 
Do the partition before you use PGP to encrypt your hard disk.